# flattenMap and error handling in ReactiveCocoa with swift

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, frp, alamofire

After reading the following tutorial http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2014/07/24/mvvm-reactivecocoa-swift.html I am trying to use ReactiveCocoa with Swift with in of my apps. When button is pressed I am making a request to check if server is responding:

```
_checkButton.rac_signalForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
.flattenMap({(text: AnyObject!) -> RACStream! in
  return RACSignal.createSignal({ (subscriber: RACSubscriber!) -> RACDisposable! in
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://google.com")
    .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
    .response{ (_, _, _, error) in
      if(error == nil) {
        subscriber.sendNext(true)
        subscriber.sendCompleted()
      } else {
        subscriber.sendError(error)
      }
    })
}).subscribeNextAs({ (value: AnyObject) -> () in
  println("success")
}, error: { (error: NSError) -> () in
  println("error")
}, completed: {})
```

When `sendError()` is called in `flattenMap` the signal is no more emmited when I am pressing the button. It works correctly as long as I am emitting `sendNext()` and `sendCompleted()` only.

Any clue on how to resolve this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sendError` is causing the signal to terminate.  From the [ReactiveCocoa Design Guidelines](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/DesignGuidelines.md#errors-are-propagated-immediately):

> In RAC, error events have exception semantics. When an error is sent on a signal, it will be immediately forwarded to all dependent signals, causing the entire chain to terminate.

If you want to `sendError` from your created RACSignal you'll need to use something like the `-catch:` operator to handle it downstream (before the subscribeNext) so it doesn't terminate the signal.

Comment: You were right. Sending an error unsubcribes from the event stream and only way to prevent it is to catch and emit an empty RACSignal.